# Uneven ACQ on Treated Pine Post Caps

Tags: pine, green

I bought some "pineapple" post caps made of treated pine. When they arrived, I was taken aback to see, rather than an overall greenish tinge, splotches and patches of green. I tried to attach a photo but can't--something about needing "at least 10 reputation to post images"?!? I realize it'd be a lot easier if you could see a photo, but can anyone advise what went wrong? As my plan has been to leave these unstained, I will probably have to send them back-- unless someone knows how to "fix" this problem? Does anyone know of a company etc that sells a similar--hopefully better treated--product? I've had a hard time finding pineapple post caps like this, but I just don't think I can use these in their present condition.

Comment: Upload a photo to imgur.com and then post the link here. We'll add it to your question for you.